# Get x509 certificate by subject alternate name - c++

Tags: c++, certificate, x509certificate, x509, subject-alternative-name

I'm trying to retrieve certificates from the local store by subject alternate name. Currently, the only option I see if to retrieve it by subject name.  This is my code:

```
PCCERT_CONTEXT GetCertFromSubject(const std::wstring& subjectName)
{
    PCCERT_CONTEXT cert = nullptr;

    HCERTSTORE hStoreHandle = CertOpenStore(
        CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
        0,
        nullptr,
        CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER,
        L"MY");

    if (hStoreHandle == nullptr)
    {
        // throw
    }

    cert = CertFindCertificateInStore(
        hStoreHandle,
        X509_ASN_ENCODING,
        0,
        CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR,
        subjectName.c_str(),
        nullptr);

    CertCloseStore(hStoreHandle, CERT_CLOSE_STORE_CHECK_FLAG);

    return cert;
}
```

This works great if I pass in the subject name to the function. I would like to look up by SAN, but don't see any options. Appreciate any help here!

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `nullptr` rather than C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: @tadman Updated the code

Comment: Looks like this is not possible. Lookups are only allowed by subject name and not subject alternate name.

Comment: Can you enumerate all certificates and test?